# how to check a string against elements in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, twitter

I am using the twitter stream api. I am currently using follow & track parameters but the API combines them with an OR and I want to combine them with an AND. The only way logically to do this is to manually check that the tweet contains a userID# in my array of userIDs to follow and the tweet text contains a keyword from my array of keywords to track.

I have converted the tweet object and tweet.text object into a JSON string like this:

```
            var tweetText = JSON.stringify(tweet.text);
            var tweetObject = JSON.stringify(tweet);
```

I want an if statement like this:

```
            if tweetObject == a value in tracked ids array && tweetText == a value in tracked words array 
                do the rest of my code
```

How can I achieve this? I tried to use .indexOf() but that takes only one parameter so I could say:

```
            if(tweetObject.indexOf("12345678") > -1 && tweetText.indexOf("spotify") > -1) {
                do my code
            }
```

But this is NOT what I want, I want it to go through the array and see if tweetObject and tweetText contain any of the array elements and if so do the code

this is what I have:

```
            // start twitter
            t.stream(
                "statuses/filter",
                {follow: trackedHandles, track: trackedWords, lang: "en" },
                function(stream) {
                    stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
                      //convert tweet.text& tweet.entities into two strings
                      var tweetText = JSON.stringify(tweet.text);
                      var userName = JSON.stringify(tweet.entities);
                      var tweetObject = JSON.stringify(tweet);
                      var flag = false;

                     for (var x = 0; x < trackedHandles.length; x++) {
                      //console.log(trackedHandles[x].toString());
                      var searchParam = tweetObject.indexOf(trackedHandles[x].toString());
                      if(searchParam != -1) {
                        flag = true;
                        //console.log(searchParam);
                        //console.log(trackedHandles[x].toString());

                        //incriment the keywords, and store the keywords as keys in redis (as they appear in feed)
                        for (var i = 0; i < trackedWords.length; i++) {
                          if(tweetText.indexOf(trackedWords[i]) > - 1) {
                            // incriments added value to the word
                            console.log(trackedWords[i]);
                            redisClient.incr(trackedWords[i]); 
                          }
                        }

                        //if tweetText does not contains "RT" & "@", print tweet to console.
                        if(tweetText.indexOf("RT") == -1 && tweetText.indexOf("@") == -1) {
                          //console.log(tweetText + "\r\n ");
                          //console.log(screen_name + "\r\n ");
                          //console.log(tweet);
                        } 
                      }
                    }

                    }); 
                }
            );
```

Please help guys, this is for my senior project for my undergrad degree. I have most of the app it self complete, I just need this one piece because What I am trying to accomplish is to only stream tweets from specific users based on specific keywords. If you can think of a more appropriate title for this please let me know. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: what is wrong with this
  ` if(tweetObject.indexOf("12345678") > -1 && tweetText.indexOf("spotify") > -1) {
                do my code
            }`
and what do you mean by **any of the array elements**.
A sample tweetText and tweetObject would be more helpful.

Comment: whats wrong with it is it takes an single element "12345678" or "spotify" and that would mean I would have to do one for each and every userID and each and every keyword I'm using. That's not a big issue now, but I plan to have 50 user ids, and several keywords. That would be one huge if statement.

Comment: i have var trackedHandles = [list of twitter userids] and var trackedWords = [list of keywords] and I want the if statement to check if tweetObject and tweetText contains one of the elements in the respective arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for or forEach loop

```
var tweetObjArr= [1,2,3,4,5]; 
var tweetIds = [7,3]
var flag = false;
for (var i = 0; i < tweetIds .length; i++) {
  if(tweetObjArr.indexOf(tweetIds [i]) != -1) {
    flag=true;
    break; 
  }
}
```

Comment: that's what I am doing. I just updated what I have currently or at least I am about to up in the main part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Might be you want `jQuery.inArray` function like

```
if(jQuery.inArray("12345678", tweetObject)!==-1)
```

Comment: yeah but that only takes one parameter "12345678" I want  to be able to feed it the array and it cycle through the elements and check if it contains that element